# Python: Returning reference to a class property from another function instead of the actual value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine a basic python class with a property like :

```py
class Test(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, x: T):
        self.__x = x
    
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x
    
    def update(self, value: T):
        self.__x = value # Note that this can be any kindof update depending on the datatype
```

and now I have a factory function that creates multiple of these class objects. I want the factory function to return the class property `x` instead of the value of `x` at the given point.
For simplicity sake, the factory function here only generates a single class.

```py
def test_factory(value: T):
    obj = Test(value)
    return obj.x, obj.update

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_property, test_setter = test_factory(10)
    print(test_property)
    test_property = 2
    print(test_property)
    test_setter(12)
    print(test_property)
```

I would like the output here to be and would expect an error at `test_property = 2`

```bash
10
10
12
```

But currently the output is :

```bash
10
2
2
```

This is because returning obj.x returns the actual value at that point which is `10`
and then `test_property` variable is getting set to `2`
Is there a way I can make the test_factory return the actual property that is `x` so it behaves like I'm using `obj.x`. I know this can be resolved by returning something like a `getX` function from `Test` class but is there any way to do this with this syntax. I want the output of the `test_factory` to be like a value and not a getter function.

---

I also tried returning `property(obj.getX())` type syntax but this returned a property object and did not have similar behavior to `obj.x`

Comment: Obligatory: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/11082165)

Comment: _"is there a way I can make the test_factory return the actual property"_ TL;DR: not really. There's no way to have any special behavior without an attribute lookup. Assignments to variables always happen the same, regardless of the values at play.

Comment: Could you comment on what your use case is / what problem you're trying to solve by doing this? There's a risk of this being an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/478746). Someone may be able to suggest an alternative you haven't considered

Comment: @Brian61354270 this was an experimental thing where I was trying to make something like a `useState` React hook but in python. And I thought @property decorators were the solution to this but got stuck at this step.

Comment: I'm still curious about what exactly happens under the hood when I write `obj.x` in my code to access a @property in python class, Since there is a getter function for it. I must be called from somewhere. And Is there any way I can overwrite or duplicate that here for my use case.

Comment: Properties are implemented using descriptors. You can read about them in  [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and [Python descriptor vs property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12846116/11082165). `obj.x` works because `obj` doesn't have a `x` attribute, by its class `Test` does. `Test.x` has `__get__`/`__set__`/`__del__` methods, which get called on the instance `obj` whenever you access `obj.x`.